# Wordpress multiste sign-up

Tags: wordpress, registration

I need to register an user only in the current blog. When I go to http://multisite.com/subblog/wp-login.php?action=register it redirects to http://multisite.com/wp-signup.php. If I register an user here then I have acces to all blogs and I don't want this.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Wordpress Multisite setup? If so, from my experience I think that you need to login to the main control panel as the superadmin. After that, at the top of the sidebar in the control panel there should be a network settings button.

Click that, and from there you should be able to access a list of blogs in the install, and from there you can select an individual blog and add users from there.

The key is that with a multiuser setup you can access all blog settings from the one superuser account which might be why you're having the redirect issue.

Comment: Thanks, in the superadmin is ok but I need the visitors can register in the front page. I've two plugins installed, one for require login to see the web (with a link to register) and other to approval new user registrations.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, could you post the names of the plugins you have installed? By any chance, have any of the plugins you're using been either fully custom built for you, and/or are they plugins which you've bought/downloaded and made significant changes to the code?

Comment: Private WP and New User Approve. I downloaded this plugins but they don't change the redirect

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Yesterday I had a family emergency so I was away from my desk. I'm doing some client work today but I'll try looking into the issue this evening.